# Relationship between the initial value of the recurrecne relation to the limit

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursion

Let $a_1$ be the first term of of sequence. Now define

$$a_{n+1}=R(a_n)$$
where R is any recurrence relation. Assuming that $\lim_{n\rightarrow }a_n$ exists , I am looking for a relationship between the limit and the first term of the sequence. Is there any known relationship(as general as possible) between the first term and the limit involving $R$?

Comment: Take $R(x)=\frac{x}{x+1}$. With both $a_1=1$ or $a_1=2$ the limit is $0$.

Comment: @egreg Does that mean we don't have a general relation between the initial point and the limit ?

Comment: Of course not; with the give recursion, which gives $1,1/2,1/3,\dotsc$, you can start at whatever point of the sequence.